# Java : Getting a substring from a string after certain character

Tags: java

I have a string

```
create table temp_username_current_timestamp.....
```

I would like to extract `"temp_username_timestamp"` from it.
Can someone please provide me some help?

Comment: Why "temp_username_timestamp"? (and not, say, "temp_current_timestamp" or "username_current_timestamp"?)

Comment: heres the stringAPI. read it and use it. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

Comment: Can you provide us an example string and/or you've tried?

Comment: Use a regex to do this.

Comment: temp_username_timestamp is not part of the initial string...how would you extract it from it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that "temp_username_current_timestamp" is not known and is expected to be different every time but you know the word or specific character that precedes what you want to extract, you should use indexOf(String str):

```
String input = "create table temp_username_current_timestamp other params"
String precedes = "table";
String extracted;

//Get the index of the start of the word to extract
int startIndex = input.indexOf(precedes) + precedes.length;
//Check if the word we are looking for is even there
if(startIndex > -1){
    //Get the index of the next space character
    int endIndex = input.indexOf(" ", startIndex);

    //If there are more parameters following ignore them
    if(endIndex > -1){
        //Extract the parameter given the indexes found
        extracted = input.substring(startIndex, endIndex);  
    } else {
        //If we are at the end of the string just extract what remains
        extracted = input.substring(startIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the input.It solved my problem.Only one change that needs to be done to make it work in this particular case: startIndex = startIndex+1;

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to work with `substrings`:

```
    String s = "create table temp_username_current_timestamp";
    int start = s.indexOf("temp");
    String t = s.substring(start, s.length()); // temp_username_current_timestamp
    int start2 = t.indexOf("_current");
    String u = t.substring(0, start2); // temp_username
    int start3 = t.indexOf("_timestamp");
    String v = t.substring(start3,t.length()); // _timestamp
    String result = u + v; // temp_username_timestamp
    System.out.println(result);
```

Output:
`temp_username_timestamp`

Answer (score 0):

Below is a regex code in Java to find a word starting with `temp_username`

```
public static void findWord() {
   String input = "create table temp_username_current_timestamp";
   String regex = "\\btemp_username[^\\s]*";
   Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
   Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(input);
   String result = "";
   if (matcher.find()) {
      result = matcher.group();
   }
   System.out.println("Found " + result);
}
```

prints: Found temp_username_current_timestamp